# How to debug crash log on Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)

Tags: swift, core-data, crash, nscalendar, xcode-organizer

Getting a crash log in my production app that seems to only be affecting one user (according to the crash logs in Organizer + a user email). However the crash log doesn't point to an issue that I understand. Here's a screenshot of the crash log:

[image]

The problem is I don't understand what this icu::Calendar::clear() is. Here's the crash in the project:

[image]

Which is initialized here as a calculated property within a `NSManagedObject` object:

```
@objc var day: String { get {
    return Day(date: self.startTime).toString()
}}
```

I realize this isn't a lot to go on but what I'd really like is help with where to go from here. Usually crash logs will tell me the actual error but I have no idea what goes wrong here and I'm completely unable to reproduce it myself. I wonder if it's an interaction with Core Data, like some thread issue? Any ideas on how to further debug that?

Comment: When you get a crash like this, it can be helpful to try to figure out what the user was doing at the time of the crash, if possible, and try to reproduce those circumstances while running the app with the [Address Sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early) enabled, to see if you can figure out whether you have threading or memory corruption issues going on. Specifically, the code you show doesn't _appear_ to have an issue, but memory corruption can hit unexpected parts of an app.

Comment: I would look at trying to play with time format changes on a device: set some format (e.g. 12 vs 24-hour clock), cause your app to save something in core data; change time to another format (e.g. back to previous format, or yet another format / locale) and now get your app to read previously saved data. I would put my bet on some data incompatibility that particular user has in their core data due to some format changes.

Comment: I would guess it is related to the user device calendar being set to something like Buddhist, Chinese or Japanese.